# Actionbar will not align correctly (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design my *actionbar* to have the *textview* in the dead center of the *actionbar*, and an *imageview* on the far right of the *actionbar*, but I just cannot get the image to align all the way right.

The image will push my *textview* left and will leave a lot of space to the right of the *imageview* no matter what different attributes I change.

Here is the *action_bar* custom XML layout which is inflated in my activity.

```xml
[![

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/users"
            android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Location"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an example of what is happening

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toolbar instead of action bar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#03a9f4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/profile_setup"
        android:id="@+id/title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/join"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:id="@+id/actionButton"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Issue is fixed :). Thank you very much!